# SUMIF minimum-so-far condition

Tags: excel, function, sum

I am trying to set up a smart conditional summing within Excel. But the range of functions available doesn't appear to provide what I am looking for.

I have two columns of numbers. In A, I have what we'll call indentation levels. In B, I have values.

For any particular row that has child indentations, I want to use a formula in B that will calculate the sum of values in B from the next row down to the next instance of that row's A value *if* the corresponding value in A is the minumum it has been *so far*.

e.g.

```
row |  A   |  B   | calc'd
--------------------
  1 |  0   |    9 |  y
  2 |    2 |    2 | 
  3 |   1  |    7 |  y
  4 |    2 |    3 | 
  5 |    2 |    4 | 
  6 |  0   |    5 |  y
  7 |   1  |    5 |
```

So, for row 1, the sum range will be rows 2 through 5. This part, I can do with an `OFFSET MATCH`.

The `SUMIF` should include row 2, as A2 is the minimum value in A2:A2.

Likewise, it should include row 3, as A3 is the minimum value in A2:A3.

But it should not include rows 4 or 5 in the sum, because their A-column values are not the minimum "so far". (These values have already been "summed up" into row 3.)

How do I create a ranged sumif with this "minimum-so-far" condition?

Comment: As you are trying to sum the same column in which you are placing same values, the best bet is vba.  A formula will not be prudent as you would need to put the formula in those spaces that need to be summed leaving the value in those that do not.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to do the source values and the sums in the same column. Because, in the above example, Row 1 = row 2 + row 3, and row 3 = row 4 + row 5. The effective condition is "sum if col A value is minimum _so far_". If I don't, I would need an even more convoluted formula. I could do this easily if I didn't allow the double-indent that is A2, so B1 would only sum the items that are at indent-1. But that's not flexible enough for real-world users.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this. Not quite as clean as I wanted, but it does the trick:

Add a helper value to column C, which is the "parent row" is will sum into.

For example, C5 `{=MAX(ROW($9:5)*(A$1:A4<A5))}` (note: array function).

Making the final equation for B1 `=SUMIF(C2:Cn,"="&ROW(),B2:Bn)` (where n is the upper limit of the working range).

As written here, inserting lines messes things up, but it can all be expanded with `OFFSET`s for row insertability.